# getting started with kotlin and SpringBootApplication to run some suspend fun

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend, coroutinescope

Trying to run this [repo](https://github.com/heroku/kotlin-getting-started) with some suspend functions. Can someone please give some hints?

Let say we have one

```
suspend fun log(){
        mLog.subscribeAlways<GroupMessageEvent> { event ->
        if (event.message.content.contains("Error")) {
            print("****")


        } else if (event.message.content.contains("Warning")) {
            print("Warning")
        }
    }

    mLog.Listen()  
    
  }
```

How can we trigger this log from main

```
open class Application {


    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {

            SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)

        }    
    }
}
```

What have try, it can run without error, but it didn't work as expected,
call the log function from Controller class

```
class Controller {

    @Value("\${spring.datasource.url}")
    private var dbUrl: String? = null

    @Autowired
    lateinit private var dataSource: DataSource
   
    @RequestMapping("/")
     internal suspend fun index(): String {
         mLog()
        return "index"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Suspend` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#your-first-coroutine) should be called from a coroutine. There are several coroutine builder functions: [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html), [async](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html), [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html).
Using these functions you can start a coroutine, for example:

```
runBlocking { 
    // call suspend methods
}
```

Coroutines launched with `launch` and `async` coroutine builders in a context of some [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html). They don't block the current thread. There are more info in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html).

`runBlocking` blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion.

Using `launch` coroutine builder you will not block the current thread if calling `suspend` function in it:

```
fun index(): String {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        log()
    }
    "index"
}
```

Note: in this case function `index` returns before `log` is executed. `GlobalScope` is [discouraged to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch/54336168#54336168). Application code usually should use an application-defined `CoroutineScope`. How to define a `CoroutineScope` is described in the docs and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208748/asynctask-as-kotlin-coroutine/58900195#58900195) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077592/kotlin-coroutines-handle-error-and-implementation/54078950#54078950).

If your intention is to block the current thread until `suspend` function completes use `runBlocking` coroutine builder:

```
fun index(): String = runBlocking {
    log()
    "index"
}
```

Some useful links: [GlobalScope.launch vs runBlocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842169/kotlin-coroutines-globalscope-launch-vs-runblocking/54855870#54855870), [Update UI async call with coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671817/update-ui-async-call-with-coroutines/54673087#54673087), [Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928668/suspend-function-callgetapi-should-be-called-only-from-a-coroutine-or-another/53928862#53928862).